# Creating multiple queries in Hadoop Hive using Ambari

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I'm pretty new to working in the cloud, general disclaimer!

I have set up a set of databases in Hadoop/Hive and Query them through hive view in Ambari. I run this through the Azure platform. Creating tables based on my data and saving these to my db works great, but once I attempt to create multiple separate tables in the same query, I start getting strange errors - mostly just a message simply saying "error". I have made sure that all my code runs fine when I test it separately, and by running each query by itself I can get all the way to my desired end result.

The pseudocode looks as follows - Why won't it run all at once?

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_db;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_db.table_one;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_db.table_two;

USE test_db;

CREATE TABLE test_db.table_one AS
SELECT var1, var2 FROM [datasource_one];

CREATE TABLE test_db.table_two AS
SELECT var1, var2 FROM [datasource_two];
```

Answer (score 0):

HiveView had in-built notifications which will list the details on what's wrong if you click on it. Sharing an image below with notications highlighted.

[image]

In your query exclude square braces ([]) and it should work. It will even fail if used with HIVE CLI.